# Get all resources attached to an Azure VM

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, azure-vm

I need to get all disks and NICs that one VM have into my Azure, Is there any powershell command to get this info ?

Comment: This probably belongs on ServerFault - there is no programming question here, and this is more about professional compute management. Also, please be sure to include what you've tried, errors, output issues, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below Powershell Cmdlets to pull the list of attached datadisk & Network Interfaces for a particular VM.

```
$rg=<ResourceGroupName>
$name=<virtualMachine> 

((get-azvm -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $name).StorageProfile).DataDisks

((get-azvm -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $name).NetworkProfile).NetworkInterfaces
```

Here is the sample screenshot output for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is PowerShell code using [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/what-is-azure-powershell?view=azps-7.0.0) to get the OS disk, data disks, and NICs associated to a VM:

```
# Set subscription
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# All VMs
$vms = Get-AzVm

# Targeted VM
#$vms = Get-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName

$vms | foreach {

  # VM name
  $_.Name

  # OS Disk
  $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk

  # Data Disks
  $_.StorageProfile.DataDisks | foreach { $_ }

  # NICs
  $_.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces | foreach { $_ }

}
```